# Prove that all neighborhoods in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are convex.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

**Definition**: Here a *neighborhood* of the point $\vec{c}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the set $N_{r}(\vec{c})=\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n: \lVert \vec{x}-\vec{c}\rVert_2 <r\}$ for some $r>0$, and a subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be *convex* if $\vec{x}, \vec{y}\in U, t\in[0, 1]$ implies $t\vec{y}+(1-t)\vec{x}\in U$.

**My Attempt**: Suppose $\vec{x}, \vec{y}\in N_{r}(\vec{c})$ and $t\in[0, 1]$, we then have $\Vert \vec{x}-\vec{c}\rVert_2<r$ and $\Vert \vec{y}-\vec{c}\rVert_2<r$. Now, $$\lVert t\vec{y}+(1-t)\vec{x}-\vec{c}\rVert_2=\lVert t\vec{y}-t\vec{x}+\vec{x}-\vec{c}\rVert_2\leq\lVert t\vec{y}-t\vec{x}\rVert_2+\lVert \vec{x}-\vec{c}\rVert_2<|t|\lVert \vec{y}-\vec{x}\rVert_2+r\leq|t|(\Vert \vec{y}-\vec{c}\rVert_2+\Vert \vec{c}-\vec{x}\rVert_2)+r<|t|(r+r)+r=(1+2|t|)r$$. Screeching halt.

**My Question**: How should I make $\lVert t\vec{y}+(1-t)\vec{x}-\vec{c}\rVert_2$ less than $r$? My intuition is that I need the *Cauchy-Schwarz inequality*; but I am unsure where to apply it. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever heard of path-connectedness?

Comment: Hint: $\vec{c} = t\vec{c} + (1 - t)\vec{c}$.

Comment: @ Wave Affirmative-I was a bit reluctant to use heavy machinery.

Comment: @TheoBendit Beautiful-much appreciated!

Comment: @DickGrayson so TheoBenito just gave a nice computational solution. But if you know what path-connectedness means then you are done since $\Bbb{R}^n$ is path connected and hence also $N_r(c)\subset \Bbb{R}^n$. Since this is a disk.

Comment: @Wave I see. Well thank you all the same! And I appreciate the editing.

Comment: @Wave Each subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is path -connected???????

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net no sorry I edited it. I have thought a moment too little. Sorry

Comment: @Wave Path-connectededness is a fair bit weaker than convexity. I really don't see how you get from path-connectedness to convexity in this case. Also, the easiest way to show path-connectedness of the disk is by showing convexity!

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes fair, so if you haven't seen that a disk or a ball is path connected, then it is easier to show directly convexity. But if you know that it is path connected you are already done. But I see what you mean

Comment: It sounds as if you're happy with Theo's hint, but in case it's of interest, the same proof handles open balls in an arbitrary normed space, not just Euclidean space or an inner product space. That is, Cauchy-Schwarz isn't needed.

Comment: I appreciate all the comments! They are all very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lVert t\vec{y}+(1-t)\vec{x}-\vec{c}\rVert_2 = \lVert t\vec{y}+(1-t)\vec{x}-t\vec{c} - (1-t)\vec{c}\rVert_2 = \lVert t(\vec{y} - \vec{c}) +(1-t)(\vec{x}-\vec{c})\rVert_2 \\
\le \lVert t(\vec{y} - \vec{c})\rVert_2  +\lVert (1-t)(\vec{x}-\vec{c})\rVert_2 = t\lVert \vec{y}-\vec{c}\rVert_2 + (1-t)\lVert \vec{x}- \vec{c}\rVert_2 < tr +(1-t) r = r .$$

Concerning $< $ note that not both $t$ and $1-t$ can be zero.